# Finding least cost path in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, road, cost-path

There are a lot of questions for this method, but does not fit in my case.
I have designed a network of roads, manually, and this is optimal. Max longitudinal grade of roads is 12%. (These are forest roads).
I tried to calculate least cost path with r.walk, SAGA Least cost path, and I got a result like this.
[image]

This is good result for walking, over the ridge, but not for trucks.
Is there another way to obtain the approximate result with my solution? 
[image]

On this link I have set an example of the whole project with layers [http://www.mediafire.com/download/me8vgx77vu7vtzw/LeastCost.rar], so if someone wants to try. If someone has a good example to explain it would be good.

Comment: Planning the road network means to meet some rules of design. One of them is the maximum longitudinal gradient of roads, and places that must be avoided, etc ..I had to manually draw the road network, which is quite slow. With the help of this algorithm, least cost path, I thought that the algorithm can automatically offer a path where I could develop this network. I used r.walk, and I got this result. I tried to take a start and end point check how close this algorithm will present my solution that is optimal.